# How to use FreeTTS in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, freetts

I wanted to use FreeTTS with Drupal 7. Is it possible? Is there any tutorial available? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/freetts for D6 only and unstable, but i think it is good starting point.